# Apache redirect any 503 error to a maintenance page

Tags: linux, apache

I have two vhosts in one server thats using apache - my main page is `www.alleOne.com` and the other is `www.sch2.com`. I have a custom page that if `www.sch2.com` or any other uri page in `www.sch2.com/madeup` is down a 503 error code, it should redirect to my custom page `http://www.alleOne.com/corp/en/service-unavailable.html`. This page has a timer and will redirect in 5 seconds to `www.alleOne.com` ( This part works already). I am trying to see if what I wrote below is correct? Also in the rewrites-enabled were would I add my rules under what vhost `www.alleOne.com` or `www.sch2.com`?

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=503
RewriteRule !^www.sch2.com$ http://www.alleOne.com/corp/en/service-unavailable.html [L,R=503]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `mod_rewrite`. Rewrite rules are used to modify requests, you want to modify the response (redirect based on the status). You can use `ErrorDocument` directive for your purpose.

In www.sch2.com configuration, use

```
ErrorDocument 503 http://www.alleOne.com/corp/en/service-unavailable.html
```

More information: [ErrorDocument Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument)